# Azure Blob Storage: How do I batch-create a snapshot for all blobs in a given container?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to snapshot every blob (of 1000s) in a given container (by way of backup). The only way via the UI seems to be to do this blob-by-blob. Storage Viewer at least allows for a few at a time.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Must I really resort to a for loop? :\

Can AzCopy or azure-cli help here..?

Thanks as ever

Answer (score 0):

> Must I really resort to a for loop? :\

Unfortunately yes. That's the only way to accomplish it as snapshots are taken at a blob level. You will need to list all blobs in a blob container and take a snapshot of each blob separately.

If you're looking for a tool to do this for you, may I suggest you take a look at [`Cerebrata Cerulean`](https://www.cerebrata.com/products/cerulean) (Disclosure: My company is behind this tool). This has a feature where you can take snapshot of all blobs in a container with a single click (it does it by listing all blobs first and then taking snapshot of each blob individually).